# Access denied for user 'www-data'@'localhost - how to deal with that?

Tags: php, mysql

I face with a strange problem yesterday. I have server running Debian with installed PHP 4.4.4-8 and mysql 5.5.9. That server serves a several websites. 
For some reason randomly I get that error "Access denied for user 'www-data'@'localhost' (using password: NO)" when I try to load the webpage.
If I hit refresh the page loads normally, but afer several clicks that message appears again. Username which that page use to connect to mysql server is not www-data.

Does anyone has faced similar problem ?

Comment: not to be an alarmist , but i would back up your DB .. schema and all. It might do tits up quite soon. The other possible reasons might be connected to network failing in some way or mistakes in user configuration.

Comment: *using password: NO* -- I wonder what that means.

Comment: on second thought, is there a chance that your script tries to connect to the database without username and password? E.g. by doing a `mysql_query()` without doing a `mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password)`?

Comment: username and password are set correctly

Comment: You should check the password.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`www-data` is the Debian user that runs apache and php.  If you attempt a query when you don't have a valid connection, php/mysql will attempt to create a connection using `<unix-user>@localhost` with no password.  This is where `www-data@localhost (using password:NO)` is coming from.

The most likely reason that this has started happening now (though it has been running fine for 2-years prior) is that your db load has increased to the point where some connections are unable to succeed (probably due to max_connections, or max_user_connections; though this can also result from other limits like memory, threads, etc).  When this happens, your call to `mysql_connect` will emit an error message, and return `FALSE`.  If you fail to detect this failure, then your next mysql call (probably mysql_query, or mysql_select_db) will attempt the connection to www-data@localhost -- thus causing the problem you're seeing.

I suggest enabling error reporting, and error display (as suggested by @DarkMantis) :

```
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL|E_STRICT);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Also, be sure that your call to mysql_connect is *not* preceded by a `@` sign; and make sure to check the return value.  It should look something like this:

```
$cxn = mysql_connect('localhost','yourusername','yourpassword');
if( $cxn === FALSE ) {  die('mysql connection error: '.mysql_error()); }
```

Comment: I think i get the root of the problem. Too many connections. What to to ? To increase ?

Comment: Good answer. Much better than mine xD

Comment: @jingo, you should not assume that the problem comes from too many connections.  You should ensure that your `mysql_connect()` is catching the error, printing the `mysql_error()` message, and terminating the script (as described above).  The `mysql_error()` message (taken immediately after `mysql_connect()` fails), will most likely tell you exactly what the problem is.  If that message says something like "mysql: max_connections exceeded", then we'll know what's going on.

Comment: This answer helped me a lot. I had mistyped user variable so it was treated like empty string. Enabling error reporting revealed it.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like the query that is causing the error happens when something specific is called. This could mean that when the query is called, you aren't connected to the database with the correct username/password.

Try to ensure that you are definatly connected, use `or die(mysql_error());` at the end of all your query variables to debug them.

Also, use the following two lines at the top of your php file:

```
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

That will show you any little php errors that may occur within your class/file which you may not have picked up before.

If your still having a problem after this, please post your PHP code and I will take a look at it directly.

Thanks!

Comment: Actually it should be `ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL | E_STRICT);` or just `ini_set('error_reporting', -1);`

Comment: The code of the webpage is not changed for two years. Since now I didn't see such a error. Thank you for helping me.

Comment: Actually, it will work both ways. E_ALL will still display the errors. But duely noted. Thanks.

Comment: In that case have you or anyone changed any of the database settings, maybe changed a user or possibly (not 100% sure on this) has someone changed a user in the debian system?

Comment: http://www.howtoforge.com/forums/archive/index.php/t-9347.html That thread had a simular problem to you, maybe that can help you. This site also may be beneficial: http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/folder-permissions-access-denied-for-user-www-data@localhost-745972/ Do you have shell access to the server it's running on just out of curiosity?

Comment: I have googled already. Yes I have shell access and now investigate logs.

Answer (score 1):

i faced the same problem.
The problem was in my config.php!
I simply changed the **$dbserver** from
**"127.0.0.1" -> "localhost".**
*Now the connection works again!*

Answer (score 1):

For absent-minded people, this error may happen when `mysql_query()` is called after `mysqli_connect()`, when it should be `mysqli_query()`.

Answer (score 0):

Use password 'NO'

```html
(MySQLi Object-Oriented)
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
echo "Connected successfully";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Deactivating safe mode fixed it for me:

```
Notice: mysql_connect(): SQL safe mode in effect - ignoring host/user/password information in /var/www/html/test.php on line 4
```

Answer (score -1):

For solve this problem. I had to change the connection script Using

```html
(MySQLi Object-Oriented)
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
echo "Connected successfully";
?>
```

Comment: maybe it is not a final solution, but it worked for me too