# PHP removes database connection

Tags: php, mysql

So I have a server with a PHP script. At the top I connect to the database with

```
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "mypassword") or die("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("mydatabase");
```

I know that these functions are deprecated but I would have to change way too many PHP files in order to fix this which is a problem for the future.

I do this at the top of the file and then further down after some HTML code and more PHP code I try to get some info from the database like so:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT Id, Name FROM people");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)) {
        printf("ID: %s  Name: %s", $row[0], $row[1]);  
    }
mysql_free_result($result);
```

Now I don't get any output. But it does work fine if I connect to the database right before I try to extract this information from it. To clarify, if I put the connect code right above this code.

Thanks

Comment: So. What happens when you try to run the code? Have you tried checking for errors? Is the database connection still open? Is the code inside a function?

Comment: No output. I have, read further down, I have now have no default database after some changes to the php.ini file. I'm not closing the connection anywhere and the code is not inside a function.

Answer (score 2):

Save the "connection" to a variable, to make a link variable, and use it as a parameter in your query.

```
$link = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "mypassword")
```

then, later use it like:

```
$result = mysql_query('SELECT * from XYZ',$link);
if (!$result) {
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}
```

Comment: That didn't solve but provided me with a great clue.

Invalid query: Access denied for user 'www-data'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Is what the error outputted. But that's really weird considering that I'm using the same username and password for the database when I'm connecting to the database through the commandline like so

sudo mysql -hlocalhost -uroot -ppassword

But I find it odd that this does not work(note the added spaces): 

sudo mysql -h localhost -u root -p password

Also, the error said that the user was "www-data"... Which it is not, the username is root.

Comment: This might help:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7671346/access-denied-for-user-www-datalocalhost-how-to-deal-with-that

Comment: I read that and edited my php.ini file and changed the default username and password. However I cannot set the default database so now the page just returns an error saying that no database has been selected.

Comment: Did you tried:
mysql_select_db("mydatabase",$link);

Comment: I did try that but it didn't hep :/